# Simple string-split by root and sufix algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, strings

A classic problem to split a string into its "root and suffix":

- ([Stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming)) The word "walk" is the base form for word "walking" (suffix is "ing");
- The [file path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) `/var/www` is the base path of `/var/www/myApp`;
- The string `doi:10.1038/ncomms` is the [URN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_name)-prefix for [`doi:10.1038/ncomms7368`](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/ncomms7368) and [`doi:10.1038/ncomms7666`](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/ncomms7666);
- The word "hello" is not a root for "walking" (suffix is "walking");

There are many ways to implement the same algorithm, so, what is the best? Examples in PHP, but valid for any language.

```php
/**
 * Splits a string by its root and sufix.
 * @param $str string input
 * @param $root string empty when no root, or start string
 * @return array (rootFlag,sufix) 
 */
function  str_splitByRoot($str, $root){
    ...
}
```

---

Algorithms `str_splitByRoot1()`, `str_splitByRoot2()`, ..., `str_splitByRoot5()`  or other (show more if you know). All do the same thing, are valid solutions.

```php
function  str_splitByRoot1($str, $root){
    if (strpos($str,$root)===0)
        return array($root, substr($str, strlen($root)) );
    else 
        return array( '', $str );
}

function  str_splitByRoot2($str, $root){
    $rootLen = strspn($str ^ $root, "\0");
    return array( substr($root,0,$rootLen), substr($str,$rootLen) );
}

function  str_splitByRoot3($str, $root){
    $s = explode($root,$str);
    return ( count($s)>1  && !array_shift($s) )? 
      array($root,join($root,$s)): 
      array('',$str);
}

function  str_splitByRoot4($str, $root){
    // to generalize need a secure regex, something like
    // $regex = str_replace(array('/','.','-'),array('\\/','\\.','\\-'),$root);
    $suffix = preg_replace("/^$root/",$str,1,$n);
    return $n? 
      array($root,$suffix): 
      array('',$str);
}

function  str_splitByRoot5($str, $root){
    // need also $root translating as algorithm 4.
    if (preg_match("/^$root(.+)$/",$str,$m))
          return array($root,$m[1]);
    else 
          return array('',$str);
}
```

The first is the traditional way. The last (algorithms 4 and 5) use regular expression, the second trim excess garbage from strings that are null terminated; and the  third  remember that the algorithm  is a kind of *split* (`explode` function).

All can be used with

```php
function str_sepByRoot($str,$root){
   return join(' * ',str_splitByRoot($str,$root)); 
}
print "\n".str_sepByRoot("walking","walk");
print "\n".str_sepByRoot("hello","walk");
print "\n".str_sepByRoot("walking-walk-walk","walk");
print "\n".str_sepByRoot("/var/www/myApp","/var/www/");
print "\n".str_sepByRoot("10.1038/ncomms7368","10.1038/ncomms");
```

returning

```
   walk * ing
    * hello
   walk * ing-walk-walk
   /var/www/ * myApp
   10.1038/ncomms * 7368
```

Comment: See related problem, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/92700/24276

Answer (score 1):

About "best thing"... The "principle of simplest is best"  seems valid. The number of commands, and the computational simplicity of each command.

- str_splitByRoot1: 2 fast commands (`strpos` and `substr`) and 1 condition and `strlen`
- str_splitByRoot2: 2 fast commands (`substr`) and 1 to be checked (`strspn`+`str ^ str`)
- str_splitByRoot2 optimized: 1 fast command (`substr`), 1 to be checked (`strspn`) and 1 condition.
- ...

So, my doubt was about `strspn`+`str ^ str` performance... And its time  struck me most,  was near time for *str_splitByRoot1*...

```
  $str_splitByRoot = array(
       function  ($str, $root){  // str_splitByRoot1()
            if (strpos($str,$root)===0)
                return array($root, substr($str, strlen($root)) );
           else 
                   return array( '', $str );
       },

       function  ($str, $root){ //str_splitByRoot2()
           $rootLen = strspn($str ^ $root, "\0");
           return array( substr($root,0,$rootLen), substr($str,$rootLen) );
       },
       function  ($str, $root){ //str_splitByRoot2() optimized
           $rootLen = strspn($str ^ $root, "\0");
           return array( $rootLen?$root:'' , substr($str,$rootLen) );
       },

       function  ($str, $root){  //str_splitByRoot3()
         $s = explode($root,$str);
         return ( count($s)>1  && !array_shift($s) )? 
             array($root,join($root,$s)): 
             array('',$str);
       }   

       function ($str, $root){ // str_splitByRoot5
            $root2 = str_replace(array('/','.','-'),array('\\/','\\.','\\-'),$root);
           if (preg_match("/^$root2(.+)$/",$str,$m))
                 return array($root,$m[1]);
           else 
                 return array('',$str);
       }
  );


  function str_sepByRoot($i,$str,$root){
       global $str_splitByRoot;
       global $debug;
            $func = $str_splitByRoot[$i];
            $s = join(' * ', call_user_func($str_splitByRoot[$i],$str,$root)); // $func($str,$root));
            if ($s &&  $debug)
                 print "\n ___ $s";
  }

  $debug=0;
  for ($i=0; $i<count($str_splitByRoot); $i++) {
       print "\n--- $i ---";
       $time = microtime(true); // time in Microseconds
       for($j=0;($j<333 && !$debug) || ($debug && $j<1); $j++){
            str_sepByRoot($i,"walking","walk");
            str_sepByRoot($i,"hello","walk");
            str_sepByRoot($i,"walking-walk-walk","walk");
            str_sepByRoot($i,"/var/www/myApp","/var/www/");
            str_sepByRoot($i,"DOI:10.1038/ncomms7368","DOI:10.1038/ncomms");     
       }
       echo "\n", (microtime(true) - $time) . ' elapsed';
  }
```

Result:

```
--- 0 ---
0.0037140846252441 elapsed
--- 1 ---
0.0045409202575684 elapsed
--- 2 ---
0.0040040016174316 elapsed
--- 3 ---
0.0088369846343994 elapsed
--- 4 ---
0.0075829029083252 elapsed
--- 5 ---
0.0037930011749268 elapsed
```

**Conclusion**, using `str_splitByRoot1` as reference (100%),

- `str_splitByRoot2` *optimized*  is ~105% , so for practical use it's as good as  `str_splitByRoot1`.
- `str_splitByRoot2`  is ~115%, something good when compared with `str_splitByRoot3` (~125%).
- `str_splitByRoot5` is 225%... as expected, the worst (even without  `str_replace` regex escapes).

---

... But, the performance changes (!) when using a big *root*, an [Lorem ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com/) of 800 words. The performance profile changed to:

- `str_splitByRoot2` (*optimized* or not)  ~244%... bad!
- `str_splitByRoot3`  (with direct split by `explode`) is ~120%, very good!
- `str_splitByRoot5` (regex)  ~390%, the worst of course.

So, the only that shows more "stability" (~120%)  about *root* length was `str_splitByRoot5`, and `str_splitByRoot2` is not a good replacement for  `str_splitByRoot1` in the context of big *roots*.